# how do you check your version of boost?

Tags: boost

I need to have my boost library in a version of 1.40. How do I check my version of the boost library?

I am trying to compile the PCL library, like described in http://pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html.

Comment: 1.4 is a very old version of Boost. Are you talking about 1.40, which is a very different thing?

Comment: As @Nicol noted – you probably meant 1.40, which is what the PCL library requires.

Comment: I changed the question to refer to 1.40 instead of 1.4.

Comment: thanks guys for replying. I am a newbie in C++, thats why needed your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, take a look at your [`boost/version.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/version.hpp). There is `BOOST_VERSION` macro for that:

```
// Example: for boost 1.55.0, taken from boost/version.hpp
//  BOOST_VERSION % 100 is the patch level
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 is the minor version
//  BOOST_VERSION / 100000 is the major version
#define BOOST_VERSION 105500
```

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_LIB_VERSION << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Save the above code as a cpp file. example boost.cpp. Then compile it.

```
   $ g++ boost.cpp
   $ ./a.out
   Boost version: 1_55
```

Then you will get your boost library version displayed on your terminal. The example output is printed for Boost 1.55.0.

What Karl von Moor had said is also correct. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708706/how-to-determine-the-boost-version-on-a-system) to figure it out.