# How to check in my code if BOOST is enabled?

Tags: c++, boost

I want some parts of my code to be enabled, only if boost is installed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639881/how-do-you-check-your-version-of-boost) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708706/how-to-determine-the-boost-version-on-a-system) one. However, they are meant for determining the version of boost.

So would something like this be totally safe?

```
#if BOOST_VERSION
  // boost code
#endif
```

If not, how should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make your own macro to do conditional compilation (or control it somehow with your build system).  For example:

```
#ifdef MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST
#  include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#endif
```

Then compile with `-DMYPROJ_HAS_BOOST` (or not).

You can't rely on `BOOST_VERSION` or anything else from Boost, because you don't know if you have Boost.  You could make a fake `<boost/version.hpp>` header file on systems where you don't have Boost, but that's sort of weird and no better than making your own project-specific macro.

Some compilers will let you `#include <boost/version.hpp` and only warn if it is not found; this may work but will give a dangerous-looking warning on systems without Boost, and may even fail outright.