# Make doxygen document the #ifdef parts too

Tags: c++, doxygen, c-preprocessor

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019489/how-to-check-in-my-code-if-boost-is-enabled), I have some parts in my code, that are enabled by a compilation flag.

For example I have this piece of code:

```
#ifdef MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST
  ...
#endif
```

Doxygen will leave them out, because they are omitted, since `MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST` is not defined. I solved it, with adding a `#define MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST`.

However this is not nice, because in the future (I am planning to extend the project), when the time comes to re-generate my documentation, maybe I will have forgotten about this.

Is there any way to say to Doxygen (ideally via doxywizard) to take into account these parts of my code too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you just need to disable preprocessing at all by setting `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` to `NO` in doxygen configuration file.

In `doxywizard` go to Expert -> Preprocessor and you will find `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING`. Just uncheck it to set it to `NO`.

More information about preprocessing in doxygen can be found in documentation [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html).

Comment: I am accepting this answer, because it's more general.

Comment: But this solution is not much convenient when we want to document the preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 14):

In your `Doxyfile` (or whatever you've renamed it to) add the lines

```
PREDEFINED = MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST
```

You can also do this in doxywizard by setting the variable `PREDEFINED` to include `MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST`.

Comment: Didn't check it, but probably will work. However, then I may change me flag and the setting will go to waste. +1 though, since I might (for some reason which I can't think now) want to take into account only the parts with `MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST`.

Answer (score 10):

My understanding today is, that doxygen supports the defines. In your case you should enable

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
```

and set

```
PREDEFINED = MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST
```

or

```
PREDEFINED = MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST=1
```

If you want to reverse it (as you wanted it in your example) change to

```
PREDEFINED = MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST=0
```

Is is explained in more details [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't test it, but it seems OK.

Comment: This worked for me. I like it because it is precise and does not require changing the source code at all: you need only add a line to `Doxyfile.in` with the macro you wish to define; everything else is left the same. Note: this works for C as well as C++.

Answer (score 6):

Doxygen defines the macro `DOXYGEN` which you can use.

```
#if defined(MYPROJ_HAS_BOOST) || DOXYGEN
  ...
#endif
```

If you have many macros, it might be easier to add the Doxygen macro then to sync your macros with the one in the Doxyfile.

Comment: Good for a quick solution. However, I have one macro, but in several places. +1 for the simplicity though (in the trade off of power of solution).

Comment: This did not work for me. Also, it requires changing the source code, which some may consider a negative.