# Weird behaviour while using boost on different platform/gcc versions

Tags: c++, boost

I am implementing a program using the Boost libraries. The program is compiled on different platforms. I have no problems on Mac OS.

The same code generates compiler errors on different platforms. The compilers are different: on Mac OS I use gcc 4.2, on Linux gcc 4.4, ...

However, there are some errors which are very hard to explain.

I am using Boost 1.5.3. For example, I have this strange message:

```
In member function 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> > > >* FolderReader::get_filenames()':
/home/u/projects/prj/src/batch/folderreader.cpp:119: error: 
   'canonical' is not a member of 'bf'
```

where bf is defined as `namespace bf = boost::filesystem;`

and `canonical()` is invoked in this way: `bf::canonical(pp).string()` with `pp` set:

```
for(bf::directory_iterator it = bf::directory_iterator(p); it != bf::directory_iterator(); it++) {
    bf::path pp = *it;
...
```

However, it should work according to the API here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#canonical

---

NOTE:
Some other errors I have just corrected were of this type. I had to write:

```
obj.method1().method2()
```

as

```
class2 &obj2 = obj.method1();
obj2.method2();
```

otherwise I would receive an error message.

So... what's wrong with my invocation of `boost::filesystem::canonical(...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure that you are using version 3 of `boost::filesystem`, which was a significant change including the addition of `canonical()`.  You may need to upgrade your boost installation or [define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) to get V3.

Even if you have boost 1.53 installed you'll need to [make sure that your code is being built against it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708706/how-to-determine-the-boost-version-on-a-system).  Your OS may have a default version that is being picked up.  For example, the Debian squeeze repository (the current stable release) is on boost 1.42 which does not contain `boost::filesystem` V3 at all.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was caused by a different version chosen by CMake in collaboration with the OS.