# cmake in Ubuntu 22.04 cannot find Boost

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I need to build a C++ program with CMake but it cannot find Boost.

I'm getting the following error no matter what solutions I've found online for other people with this problem...

```
-- Compiling with C++ standard: 17
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least
  version "1.68.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (find_package)
```

This is the part of my CMakeLists.txt looking for Boost

```
if(NUMCPP_NO_USE_BOOST)
    target_compile_definitions(${ALL_INTERFACE_TARGET} INTERFACE -DNUMCPP_NO_USE_BOOST)
else()
    find_package(Boost 1.68.0 REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(${ALL_INTERFACE_TARGET} INTERFACE Boost::boost)
endif()
```

I have installed boost with `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` and a few other apt-get options. I always see `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove` after running.

$ whereis boost
boost: /usr/include/boost

Do I need to specify it in the cmake .. line in the terminal somehow?

Comment: What version of boost is installed?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where to look for that. I've only run `apt-get` commands to install it.

Comment: Did you consider using a package manager... will make your life much way easier. Some options are conan and vcpkg.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've successfully installed boost in the default directory, and CMake has access to those directories, probably the problem (as @drescherjm mentioned) is in the version of the Boost you've installed (sometimes the packages provided by `apt-get` are relatively old).
On the other hand it can also be that CMake doesn't have the installation directory in its search path.

The following steps might be a good place to start:

1. Check the version of the Boost installed: [How to determine the Boost version on a system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708706/how-to-determine-the-boost-version-on-a-system) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147474/how-can-i-find-boost-version)

If the version installed by `apt-get` satisfies the project requirement, it seems for some reason CMake didn't include a directory of installation to its searching path. If that's the case, skip to the *step 3*.

2. If it's lower than your project requires, build it from [source](https://www.boost.org/users/download/) (right now 1.80 is available) to your preferred directory. If you need the libraries which need to be built, check this [tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html).
3. Tell CMake where to search for built Boost. See here: [Cmake doesn't find Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808775/cmake-doesnt-find-boost)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this reply is not too off-topic. I suggest you consider using a package manager such as [conan](https://conan.io/) or [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/index.html).

An example of using `conan` to use external dependencies.

#### 1. Create `conanfile.txt`

It should have the following content:

```
[requires]
boost/1.80

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

#### 2. Download your dependencies

```
mkdir build && cd build
conan install .. --build=missing
conan build ..
```

The last command is optional and can be changed with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake ..
```

#### Benefits:

- You don't need to "mess" your system with different libraries
- Transitional dependencies are handled automatically
- The build process is reproducible